# What state is the running process in when waiting for a UAC confirmation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uac

If I run a process that requires a UAC confirmation from the user, the Windows UAC prompt appears and waits for the user to confirm the action. With the UAC prompt open, if I look at the list of running processes, the original application appears.

What state is this process in? Presumably it has started running as it appears as a process, but it cannot have done anything yet as that would surely defeat the purpose of UAC.

Comment: Do you mean a process that has the elevation required flag set in it's manifest, or a process that requests elevation after it starts?

Comment: @Hello71: The second case. The process has tried to do something that requires administrative rights.

Comment: Is UAC virtualization enabled for the process?

Comment: @Hello71: No, it is not.

Comment: Then the process has to explicitly request elevation, and the thread requesting elevation is blocked until the call returns. Same as any other waiting call (networking, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be helpful   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756945.aspx

[image]

Found that link here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The process is given an ID ready for launch, if you block access the process is terminated, the process is just in memory but contains no data until allow is pressed.